# RegExp: удаление строк медиа-запросов в Notepad++

Tags: css, регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Нужно вырезать все запросы `@media` из файла CSS. Например есть следующий CSS-код:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-list.filter-buttons .dropdown-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .filter-list.filter-buttons .dropdown-menu {
    background: none;
    border: 0 none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    display: block !important;
    float: none;
    left: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: inherit;
    z-index: inherit;
  }
}
```

Составил такую регулярку - `@media[^\{]*{[^\}]*}`, но она работает только до первого `}`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Может, `@media[^{]*({(?:[^{}]++|\g<1>)*})`? См. https://regex101.com/r/JdOseV/1

Comment: На regex101 php такое принимает, а вот js и notepad++ нет. Но суть понял.

Comment: JS не поймет. А в Notepad++ это какой-то баг. Используйте SublimeText.

Comment: Кстати, у вас нет требований к языку в вопросе. Значит, даже [ответ на Lua](https://ideone.com/QLJNPK) (`@media[^{]*%b{}`) корректен :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если для Npp и код CSS отформатирован, то:

Найти: `@media.*?\{([\s\S]*?)[^ \t]\}`

Заменить на: `\1`

Comment: В notepad++ (NPP) работает неккоректно

Comment: @Shillkas Поправил ответ.